# Problems when linking shared library

Tags: c, makefile, shared-libraries

Below are the steps of how I generate the executable file using shared library.

1. I have three files:

   **File libhello.c**

   ```
   /* hello.c - demonstrate library use. */
   #include <stdio.h>
   void hello(void)
   { 
       printf("Hello, library world./n");
   }
   ```

   **File libhello.h**

   ```
   /* hello.h - demonstrate library use. */
   void hello(void);
   ```

   **File main.c**

   ```
   /* main.c -- demonstrate direct use of the "hello" routine */
   #include "hello.h"
   int main(void)
   {
       hello();
       return 0;
   }
   ```
2. I use the commands below to generate the shared library.

   ```
   gcc -g -Wall -fPIC -c hello.c -o hello.o
   gcc -shared -W,soname,-libhello.so.0 -o libhello.so.0.0.0 hello.o
   ```
3. Finally, I add the library path to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable and try to create the executable file using the shared library.

   ```
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
   ln -s libhello.so.0.0.0 libhello.so.0
   gcc -g -Wall -c main.c -o main.o -I.
   gcc -o main main.o -lhello -L.
   ```

However, at the last step, there is one error: can't find -lhello. So, where am I wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gcc` looks for `libhello.so` when linking a new program. `libhello.so.0` is used when the dynamic dependencies of an already linked program are searched.

In other terms: `gcc -o main main.o -lhello -L.` looks for `libhello.so`, and `./main` looks for `libhello.so.0`. This allows to have multiple versions of a library available for legacy programs while precisely identifying the library that matches the installed headers.

A symlink `libhello.so` -> `libhello.so.0.0.0` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
So, you mean that on the linking phase of the first time compliling, we need to create an additional symlink to play the trick using `ln` command? Is it conventional? All the project using shared library should play this trick?

Comment: @thiton is telling you to change your `ln` command to `ln -s libhello.so.0.0.0 libhello.so`. Incidently here's the identical question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411049/gcc-shared-library-problems]

Comment: @acraig5075 , so each time I update the libhello.so.x.x.x, I need to let the `libhello.so` points to the new version, right? In other words, for example, I update the libhello.so.0.0.0 to libhello.so.0.0.1, I need to execute the command: `ln -s libhello.so.0.0.1 libhello.so` again, right?

Comment: @acraig5075 , how to use `ldconfig` command? I heared that it could be used to update the soft links.